# How do I create an Arbitrary for a System.Type?

Tags: testing, f#, fscheck

I am attempting to initialize my model entities using FsCheck. The models live in C# and are normally initialized via Entity Framework via their private setters. For example (contrived):

```
public class Model
{
    public string One { get; private set; } 
    public int Two { get; private set; } 
}
```

I would like to create an FsCheck generator that automatically uses the registered generator for each property to produce the model. Something like this:

```
let modelGenerator = 
    gen {
        let incident = new Model()
        typeof<Model>.GetProperties()
            |> Array.filter (fun p -> p.CanWrite)
            |> Array.iter (fun p -> 
                let! newVal = Arb.generateType p.PropertyType // I wish I could do this
                p.SetValue(incident, newVal))

        return incident
    }
```

There are two things wrong with this:

1. The `let!` can't be used outside of the `gen` computation expression.
2. `Arb.generateType` doesn't exist, and I can't find a way to do its equivalent

Is it possible to create a generator that will automatically set the private fields on my model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the power of reflection, everything is possible (or throws at runtime).

```
module Arb = 
    open System.Reflection 

    // this is just a helper type to do reflection on. 
    type internal GenerateInvoker = 
        static member Invoke<'typ> () = 
            Arb.generate<'typ>
            |> Gen.map box

    // Invokes a generic method using a runtime type as a generic argument.
    let generateType (typ: Type) =
        typeof<GenerateInvoker>
            .GetMethod("Invoke", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .MakeGenericMethod([|typ|])
            .Invoke(null, [||]) :?> Gen<obj>

let modelGenerator = 
    gen {
        let incident = new Model()
        let props =  
            typeof<Model>.GetProperties()
            |> Array.filter (fun p -> p.CanWrite)

        // gen builder implements For, so you can do something like this. 
        for prop in props do 
            let! newVal = Arb.generateType prop.PropertyType
            prop.SetValue(incident, newVal)

        return incident
    }

Gen.sample 1 3 modelGenerator
```

Comment: Worked great once I added binding flags to the GetMethod call: `typeof<GenerateInvoker>.GetMethod("Invoke", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic)`.

Comment: @Daws: right, I might have twiddled with the answer too much after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on @scrwtp's answer, generalizing and updating to FsCheck v3:

```
open FsCheck // Gen
open FsCheck.FSharp // ArbMap.generate
open System
open System.Reflection

module Gen =
    type internal Impl =
        static member GenByType<'T>(arbMap: IArbMap) = arbMap |> ArbMap.generate<'T> |> Gen.map box
    let private genByType' = typeof<Impl>.GetMethod(nameof Impl.GenByType, BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    let byType arbMap (t: Type) = genByType'.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, [| arbMap |]) :?> FsCheck.Gen<obj>

module Type =
    let isGenericWhere predicate (x: Type) = x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() |> predicate
    let private isSeq = isGenericWhere ((=) typedefof<seq<_>>)
    let elevateSeqToArray t = if isSeq t then t.GenericTypeArguments.[0].MakeArrayType() else t

let scannedTypes: Type[] = ...

/// Provides Arbitrary<obj> that generates instances of detected types
/// Includes Arbs from provided Custom Arbs Type, 'C
type ScannedModelArbs<'C> private () =
    /// FsCheck doesn't have a seq<'T> generator in the default map, wo we generate arrays instead
    static let types = scannedTypes |> Seq.map Type.elevateSeqToArray
    /// Apply the custom generation logic
    static let arbMap = ArbMap.defaults |> ArbMap.mergeWithType typeof<'C>
    static member Obj: Arbitrary<obj> = types |> Seq.map (Gen.byType arbMap) |> Gen.oneof |> Arb.fromGen
```

Used like so:

```ml
// Example custom overrides for generation
type ModelArbs private () =
    // Builds based on Arbs in the ArbMap
    static member CatalogEntry map: Arbitrary<CatalogEntry> =
        ArbMap.generate map
        |> Gen.filter (not << System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
        |> Gen.map CatalogEntry.fromId
        |> Arb.fromGen
    // Some UoM types (such as tokens, which is a `float` with a UoM) won't serialize if NaN / Infinity
    static member NormalFloats map: Arbitrary<float> = Arb.fromGen <| gen {
        let! NormalFloat f = ArbMap.generate map
        return f }

[<FsCheck.Xunit.Property(Arbitrary = [| typeof<ScannedModelArbs<ModelArbs>> |])>]
let ``can handle anything`` (instance: obj) =
    null <> instance
```